# sql query if condition

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query that `mr.Name`might be nulll so if it is null I do not want to consider it. how can I write this query that if it contains data consider it in `where` if not behave like

```
where da.LastRefreshTime >= xx and da.LastRefreshTime <= xx and 
        da.M = z
```

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT distinct ... 
FROM ...
where da.LastRefreshTime >= xx and da.LastRefreshTime <= xx and 
    da.M = z  and mr.Name in ('FRANCE','ITALY')
```

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server or C#? Pick one please. Hint: It's not C#...

Comment: Does it matter? @DavidG `where column is not null` works for both (not experienced in mySql though)

Comment: @CM2K Yes, it does matter.

Answer (score 1):

use `IS NOT NULL`

```
WHERE mr.Name IS NOT NULL;
```

> IS NOT NULL condition is used to test for a NOT NULL value
>   in a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE

Comment: `where column is not null` is also a valid sql server syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct ... 
FROM ...
where da.LastRefreshTime >= xx and da.LastRefreshTime <= xx and
    da.M = z  and ((mr.Name in ('FRANCE','ITALY') and mr.Name is not NULL) or 1 = 1)
```

I think this is what you want, try it and tell me if this solves your problem

Comment: But if it is null it does not consider the whole where part. I want it as I explained just to consider 'where da.LastRefreshTime >= xx and da.LastRefreshTime <= xx and 
        da.M = z  ' if the mr.Name is null it is like there is no filter for mr.Name

Comment: i get what you want. Wait few min to write it down

Comment: If mr.Name is France or Italy then it cannot be NULL as well, hence the check for _and mr.Name is not NULL_ is not useful.

Comment: @Kickstart, you are right, I will think about a new approach

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to return rows where Name is France, Italy or NULL. As such just add an OR clause and brackets:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT ... 
FROM ...
WHERE da.LastRefreshTime >= xx 
AND da.LastRefreshTime <= xx 
AND da.M = z  
AND (mr.Name IN ('FRANCE','ITALY')
OR mr.Name IS NULL)
```

Comment: no I want to ignore the filter mr.Name in where clause if mr.Name is null. in case mr.Name is null I want the query to ignore it like :    where da.LastRefreshTime >= xx and da.LastRefreshTime <= xx and 
        da.M = z

Comment: Sorry, afraid I cannot see the difference. This query will bring back rows where the row is filtered for France or Italy, but if Name is null then it is also returned (if it meets the other WHERE clauses).

Comment: @Kickstart please see my answer, I think he wanted to remove `mr.Name IN ('FRANCE','ITALY')` if the `mr.Name is null` . Did I get it right?

Comment: @CM2K - that is what I think he wants to do, which is what my query does (ie using OR if mr.Name is NULL then the check for France or Italy is ignored).

Comment: @Kickstart Maybe my sql skills are not as good as I thought, but I understand your query as: pseudo: and (if the name is null then filter the name for France, Italy). But from the question I understand (pseudo) again: if the name is null then don't filter for france or italy. Am I getting this wrong?

Comment: @CM2K My query is checking if the name is France or Italy or NULL.

Comment: @Kickstart yea, should work. Learn something everyday :)